# Create elements in JS or duplicate from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, maintainability

I'm writing some code to populate a list of blog posts dynamically. Each blog post in the list shares the same structure, but the text content and other attributes (e.g., `href`) are different.

Originally, I was creating each of them in a JS function. The function would call `document.createElement()` for each element that goes into the post.

Then I realized that having one "template" blog post in HTML would serve as good documentation of what a post in the list looks like structurally. So, I decided to rewrite the JS function to call `Node.cloneNode()` on the "template" blog post for each post in the list and then to modify the text content, `href`, etc., to fit the actual content of the blog post. The template has `display: none`, which gets unset for each duplicate element.

Are there any benefits besides the documentation aspect of the HTML that come with the implementation I switched to? Are there benefits to the full-JS implementation? Any downsides to either approach? Thanks!

Comment: See [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

Comment: As far as performance: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/266/0/createelement-vs-clonenode#latest_results_block
   https://jsperf.com/clonenode-vs-createelement-performance/32

Comment: @zer00ne and user120242, thanks for your responses! I'll go with the `<template>` tag. I appreciate it!